# applying a function with arguments to a cell using cellfun

Tags: matlab

Suppose one has a cell array of characters that one wishes to convert to a vector of numbers. This could be accomplished using `str2num` or `str2double`. For instance,

```
x={'0.17106'; '2.11462'; '4.13938'; '6.24203'}
cellfun(@str2num,x)
str2double(x)
```

These functions are somewhat slow compared to `sscanf`. However, `sscanf` requires additional arguments, the specification of which seems not to be possible using the ordinary `cellfun` syntax, e.g.,

```
cellfun(sscanf(>variable usually goes here<,'%f'),x)
```

How does one apply `sscanf` to each element of a cell array, or more generally, how does one apply any function requiring an ordered series arguments using `cellfun`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this very fast, do not use either `cellfun` or `str2double`.  Some possibilities:

### `strjoin` with `sscanf`

Use [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) to combine the strings in cell array `x` into a single long space-delimited string, which can then be parsed very quickly with `sscanf`:

```
sscanf(strjoin(reshape(x,1,[])),'%f')
```

Note the `reshape` is included to guarantee the cell array is a row, as required by `strjoin`. A simple permute (`.'`) could be used if you know `x` is a column, or nothing if `x` is already a row.

### `vertcat` (or `str2mat`) with `sscanf`

Instead of `strjoin`, form a virtual [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of strings with `x{:}` and vertically concatenate them with [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) (if each string has the same number of characters). Transpose this 2D character array and `sscanf` can again parse it quickly in a single shot:

```
sscanf(vertcat(x{:})','%f');
```

Or if the number of characters varies from string to string, you can use `str2mat`, which creates a space-padded 2D character array that `sscanf` also happily reads:

```
sscanf(str2mat(x)','%f');
```

### test

Create a cell array of string representations of 10,000 random numbers:

```
>> x = sprintfc('%f',rand(1e4,1));
```

Note the use of the undocumented `sprintfc` to print to cells.

Reference methods:

```
>> tic; d0 = str2double(x); toc
Elapsed time is 0.302148 seconds.
>> tic; d1 = cellfun(@(x) sscanf(x,'%f'),x); toc
Elapsed time is 0.277386 seconds.
>> isequal(d0,d1)
ans =
     1
```

`strjoin` and `vertcat`:

```
>> tic; d2 = sscanf(strjoin(reshape(x,1,[])),'%f'); toc
Elapsed time is 0.068129 seconds.
>> isequal(d0,d2)
ans =
     1
>> tic; d3 = sscanf(vertcat(x{:}).','%f'); toc
Elapsed time is 0.024312 seconds.
>> isequal(d0,d3)
ans =
     1
>> tic; d4 = sscanf(str2mat(x).','%f'); toc
Elapsed time is 0.011917 seconds.
>> isequal(d0,d4)
ans =
     1
```

Note: these numbers are ballpark as then should be run over multiple iterations inside of a script or function, but all code is warmed.  Try them out.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful reply. I encountered some problems while trying to apply the `sscanf(str2mat(...).','%f')` conversion. I initially described the issue in a series of comments appended to your posted answer, but decided to make it a separate question after it became too long-winded (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21837778/873757).

Comment: I posted another follow-up question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21839291/873757). The `sscanf(str2mat(...).'` approach that you proposed takes about 15 seconds for my data set, compared to 286 seconds for `cellfun(sscanf...)` and 342 seconds for `str2double`, so the improvement factor is more than one order of magnitude! Why are the latter two so slow? Thanks again for the helpful post.

Answer (score 2):

How about a wrapper for the sscanf?

```
myWrapper = @(x) sscanf(x, '%f')
x={'0.17106'; '2.11462'; '4.13938'; '6.24203'}
cellfun(myWrapper,x)
str2double(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Is there a way to define MATLAB functions using "dummy variables" (not sure if that is the proper term). I wish to use the wrapper within another function and the 'x' doesn't yet exist (it is created by that other function). When I try to define the function using 'x' as a dummy variable, MATLAB complains that 'x' does not yet exist, which seems to imply that MATLAB cannot create a general function (that the function's input must already be defined). Surely that is not the case?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited the answer. This is the correct syntax. Look up inline function definitions in MATLAB.