# inaccurate reading of data by sscanf

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, conversion of string representations of numbers in a cell array into numeric representations in a double array can be performed with `str2double` or a combination of `str2num` and `cellfun`. A [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21794549/873757) suggested using a combination of `str2mat` and `sscanf` to achieve faster conversion. However, this approach seems to fail for certain data sets, such as the following:

```
x={'98.78743';'99.39717';'99.93578';'100.40125';'100.79166';'101.10525';'101.34037';'101.49553';'101.56939';'101.56072';'101.4685';'101.29184';'101.03002';'100.68249';'100.24887';'99.72897';'99.12274';'98.43036';'97.65215';'96.78864';'95.84054'};
y=sscanf(str2mat(x).','%f');
[str2double(x),y,str2double(x)-y]
ans =

    98.7874   98.7874         0
    99.3972   99.3972         0
    99.9358   99.9358         0
   100.4013  100.4013   -0.0000
   100.7917    0.7917  100.0000
   101.1052    0.1053  101.0000
   101.3404    0.3404  101.0000
   101.4955    0.4955  101.0000
   101.5694    0.5694  101.0000
   101.5607    0.5607  101.0000
   101.4685    0.4685  101.0000
   101.2918  101.2918   -0.0000
   101.0300    0.0300  101.0000
   100.6825    0.6825  100.0000
   100.2489    0.2489  100.0000
    99.7290    0.7290   99.0000
    99.1227   99.1227         0
    98.4304   98.4304         0
    97.6522   97.6522         0
    96.7886   96.7886         0
    95.8405   95.8405         0
```

The final line in the above code block shows the double representation of the original cell array, the `sscanf`-converted form, and the difference between the two. For a faithful conversion, all entries in the third column would be precisely 0. Many of the values are converted with improper elimination of the most significant digits. What is the basis for this erroneous behavior and can the statement be modified slightly to produce an accurate conversion? In general, the numbers which I am trying to convert are of different lengths (both pre- and post-decimal point), so any approach that relies on all numbers in the cell array having the same length are bound to fail. Finally, my version of MATLAB is pre-2013, so I cannot rely on the `strjoin` approach that was also suggested in the aforementioned post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
y=sscanf(str2mat(x).','%9f')
```

The `9` actually correspond to the maximum length of numbers in `str2mat(x).'`

```
>> str2mat(x).'

ans =

999111111111111999999
899000000000000998765
...001111111100......
739............714678
893471345542062223584
775090496669384820280
417115059081028973165
378262353758048746544
   5657392 4297
```

Hence, `sscanf` will search for 9 floats and stop when it finds a space. You could define the 9 values depending on your data.

An example:

```
x={'98.7';'99.397';'99.93578';'100.4';'100.79166';'101.10'};
>> str2mat(x).'

ans =

999111
899000
...001
739...
 93471
 75 90
  7 1 
  8 6 
    6
```

Here the maximum length is still 9. And the answer is still correct.

```
y=sscanf(str2mat(x).','%9f')

>> y =

   98.7000
   99.3970
   99.9358
  100.4000
  100.7917
  101.1000
```

For determining the random length for the `%'number'f`, use:

```
size(str2mat(x).',1)
```

And another trick:

```
xMaxLength = num2str(size(str2mat(x).',1));
y = sscanf(str2mat(x).',['%' xMaxLength 'f']);
```

In order to only calculate `str2mat` one time:

```
xx = str2mat(x).';
xxMaxLength = num2str(size(xx,1));
y = sscanf(xx,['%' xxMaxLength 'f']);
```

Comment: Does the 9 come from the largest number of characters in a single column (8) plus 1 character for either padding, spacing, or newline? Will this strategy work generally for any set of numbers of varying lengths (pre- and post-decimal) as long as the largest length for a single number (+1) is selected?

Comment: @user001 I added some clarification. You can also take a look at the `sscanf` documentation in Matlab to see what the %`numbers`f does.

Comment: Secondly, is there a simple method to determine the longest length in a set of data for cases where that length is not known a priori (i.e., can the '9' value be determined as a variable from a simple expression)? Thanks again.

Comment: @user001 I added the equation for determining the longest length.

Comment: @user001 I just added a solution for having everything automatic!

Comment: Thanks, that's great! In my case, I define a function as follows: `extract_data=@(n)sscanf(str2mat(data(headerIdx(n)+1:headerIdx(n+1)-1)).','%9f')` which moves through a structured cell array (`data`) from one header line to the next (the positions of which are defined by an array `headerIdx`), converting the blocks of data between header lines into a double array. This is followed by an `arrayfun` statement that iterates through the list of all header lines. The conversion of data from a structured cell array to a cell of double arrays can therefore be made in just two lines...

Comment: ... Is it possible to modify my function definition line to use the correct `%f` length without including an additional step in which the `str2mat(x).'` intermediate value is stored in a variable? That would require modifying my strategy and would, I think, require a loop statement instead. Thanks!

Comment: @user001 I added another alternative, I don't know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that each subarray extracted from the parent array could have a different maximum length (if that makes sense). I think the additional requirements I have made greatly expand the scope of the original question, so I'll post it as a separate question.