# dynamically specifying floating point number size in a function-enclosed sscanf statement

Tags: matlab

I have a structured data file consisting of header lines interspersed with blocks of data. I am reading each block of data (as defined by the header line) into a separate cell of a cell array. For instance, suppose that after loading the data with `textscan`, I have a cell array `x` and an array of indices of header lines and EOF (`headerIdx`) of the following form:

```
x={'header line 1';'98.78743';'99.39717';'99.93578';'100.40125';'100.79166';'101.10525';'101.34037';'101.49553';'101.56939';'101.56072';'101.4685';'101.29184';'101.03002';'100.68249';'header line 2';'100.24887';'99.72897';'99.12274';'98.43036';'97.65215';'96.78864';'95.84054';'header line 3';'3.2';'4.31';'2.7';'4.6';'9.3'};
headerIdx=[1;16;24;30];
```

I then attempt to extract each block of data below a header line into a separate element of a cell array using `sscanf` and `str2mat` (as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21794549/873757)). Initially, this approach failed because the elements within a given block of data were of different length. This can be solved by including a numerical flag for the `'%f'` argument to help `sscanf` know where to delimit the input data (as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838371/873757)). One can then use a strategy such as the following to effect the conversion of structured data to a cell array of block-specific double arrays:

```
extract_data = @(n) sscanf(str2mat(x(headerIdx(n)+1:headerIdx(n+1)-1)).',['%' num2str(size(str2mat(x(headerIdx(n)+1:headerIdx(n+1)-1)).',1)) 'f']);
extracted_data = arrayfun(extract_data,1:numel(headerIdx)-1,'UniformOutput',false);
```

The numerical flag of the format string can either be set to something arbitrarily large to encompass all the data, or can be set on a block-specific basis as I have done in the example above. The latter approach leads to redundant evaluation of `str2mat` (once for the input to `sscanf` and once for the input to the `'%f'` string generator. Can this redundancy be avoided without using loop statements that store the output of the `str2mat` command in a temporary variable? Note that one cannot simply take the output of the `size` command applied to the output of `str2mat(x).'` on the entire data set because the header lines are generally going to be the lines with the greatest number of characters.

Finally, I have constructed the `x` matrix above to reflect the fact that some blocks of data may have different precision than other blocks. This is the reason to set the format string in a block-specific manner. My testing has shown that despite accurate construction of a block-specific format string (`['%' num2str(size(str2mat(x(headerIdx(n)+1:headerIdx(n+1)-1)).',1)) 'f']`), the data in all elements of the resulting cell array (`extracted_data`) are ultimately forced to have the same precision (see below). Why is this the case, and how can it be corrected?

```
extracted_data{:}

ans =

   98.7874
   99.3972
   99.9358
  100.4013
  100.7917
  101.1052
  101.3404
  101.4955
  101.5694
  101.5607
  101.4685
  101.2918
  101.0300
  100.6825


ans =

  100.2489
   99.7290
   99.1227
   98.4304
   97.6522
   96.7886
   95.8405


ans =

    3.2000
    4.3100
    2.7000
    4.6000
    9.3000
```

Comment: [The display format](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/format.html) has little to do with the stored precision.